# PHP MYSQL login script session not working

Tags: php, mysql, session

I have a small script to deal with login in to my CMS. The query works fine, but i think i have a problem with SESSIONS, because it redirects to the login page even when the username and password are correct. I have the codes below. Kindly help me resolve this. Thanks in advance.

//checklogin.php....

```
<?php
include("db/dbconnect.php");

mysqli_select_db($connect, $db);

// username and password sent from signup form
$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['username']);
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['password']);

$sql = "SELECT username, password FROM login WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$password'";
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql) or die('Error : ' .  mysqli_error($connect));

// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

// If result matched $username and $password, table row must be 1 row
if($count == 1)
{

    //Register $username, $password and redirect to mainpage"
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    $_SESSION['password'] = $password;

    header("location:about.php");
}
else {
echo "Invalid Username or Password. Please try again.";
echo "<meta http-equiv=Refresh content=5;url=index.php>";
}
?>
```

//about.php

```
<?php 
//check if user is logged on;
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['username']) )
{
    header("location:index.php");
}
?>
```

Comment: You have to start the session in every script that makes use of it (generally bung it in an include that's called on every page)

Comment: yes i have "session_start();" on all pages that require authentication

Comment: checklogin.php contains no session_start()

Comment: yeah i noticed that, and it works now. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add   session_start(); in checklogin.php
This will help you

```
<?php
 session_start();  //missing in checklogin.php
include("db/dbconnect.php");
mysqli_select_db($connect, $db);
```

Comment: thanks very much man! it worked. i spent a week on this before i decided to bring it here. God bless u man.

Answer (score 1):

You need to start the session before assigning username and password to it. In your "If" condition ($count ==1), you are directly assigning username and password. Put this line before these assignments:

session_start();

So, now your "If" condition becomes this:

```
if($count == 1)
{

    session_start();
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    $_SESSION['password'] = $password;

    header("location:about.php");
}
```

I guess, that's what the issue is. Let me know, if it works.

Comment: i have one already marked, is it possible to mark multiple answers as correct?

Comment: I guess not. Well, thanks for the upvote !! No issues.